# Question about absolute value and complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

Let M be the set of all complex numbers such that:

| z+(2-7i) | = or < 4. (equal or/and less than four)

and show where M lies in the complex plane.

---

So I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to measure the distance from Z to 2-7i and draw the area in the complex plane, but I have a few questions about Z + (2-7i), because distance between is usually denoted with "-" instead of "+", is it not? Like l z - w l is the distance between two points.

Does that mean I can write the expression as z - -(2-7i) instead (because - and - is +)?

Do I then have to change the sign inside the paranthesis as well, so it becomes l z - -2+7i l , or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: $z+(2-7i) = z-(-2+7i)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You just write $|x+yi+2-7i|\leq\,4$ which gives
$(x+2)^{2}+(y-7)^{2}\leq\,16$